# How can i remove from a pictureBox the background image only and leave on the pixels i drawed?

Tags: c#

This is the Play button code:

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _files = new List<FileInfo>(); 
            _indx = 0;
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filesForanimation);

            if (_files == null)
                _files = new List<FileInfo>();

            fi1 = dir.GetFiles("*.bmp");
            _files.AddRange(fi1);

            _files = _files.OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime).ToList();
            button14.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            button13.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            button12.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            timer3.Start();
            button13.Enabled = true;
            button13.Text = "Pause";
            button12.Enabled = true;
            trackBar1.Maximum = fi1.Length;
            trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
        }
```

Then the timer tick event:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Image iOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
                trackBar1.Value = _indx;
                label23.Text = _files[_indx].Name;

            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(_files[_indx].FullName);
                this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
                this.pictureBox1.Image = null;
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(_files[_indx].FullName);
                this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
            }
            if (iOLd != null)
                // iOLd.Dispose();
                _indx++;

            if (_indx >= _files.Count)
            {
                _indx = 0;
                trackBar1.Value = 0;
            }
                timer3.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value); 
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

And the checkBox check event:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked) 
            {
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
                g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Load(fi[trackBar1.Value].FullName);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

The problem is in the timer tick. First time i tried inside the if (checkBox1.Checked) i did only pictureBox1.Refresh(); but then when hitting play button its showing big red X with white background. So i marked // the line: iOLd.Dispose(); so now i see the drawings the pixels only but they never change i guess for some reason it dosent load the new image from the hard disk as it suppose to do so its keep moving over and over the same image.

So i tried in the if (checkBox1.Checked)
to do as it is now:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(_files[_indx].FullName);
                    this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
                    this.pictureBox1.Image = null;
                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

But in this case the trackBar and the timer moving once to image number 2 and stop there without doing anything.

And this happennig only when the checkBox is checked if its not checked and in the pictureBox there are the pixels and the background image its working fine.

** I modified cleared and made the question shorter **

Answer (score 1):

You should not draw onto a graphics object from a non-persisted method such as a check change event.

You should handle the [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event of the PictureBox so that your graphics are redrawn each time the `PictureBox` needs to refresh (such as when changing the background image). As it stands you will most likely lose your graphics if you move the window around enough too.

For example:

```
pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;
   // draw your pixels here
}
```

**NOTE**: Picture boxes have there uses and there problems, if you want to do custom drawing I would recommend just drawing onto a standard panel instead.